# ActiveRecord - trying to use a Join in OR and getting "Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using Rails 6.1.4.7 and Ruby 3.0.3, I am attempting to use a join in an ActiveRecord OR statement, and am getting the error message: "Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]"

The goal of the query is to create a Relation that has:

1. All entries where the company id is nil, plus,
2. All entries where, when the company id is not nil, the company_number field of the associated company is nil

My statement is:

```
r.where(company_id: nil).or(r.joins(:company).where("companies.company_number is null"))
```

I cannot just do two queries and add them together because this results in an Array, where I need the result to be a Relation.

Is there any way that I can achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance for your help!

(I have added additional detail and simplified the query)

Comment: You need to actually tell us what the goal is and show use the models, schema and an expected result. Its not actually clear what it is that this code is actually supposed to do and there is most likely a much better solution altogether to the original problem.

Comment: Using `.map(&:company_id)` doesn't actually make any sense. You're forcing a second query to fetch the data when you could use a subquery and there is no reason why you should use a SQL string here.

Comment: @max -Thanks for your input. I have simplified the query to remove parts that weren't relevant to the problem I was experiencing and updated with a (hopefully) more precise statement of the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, this was resolved by swapping the order of the command.

```
r.joins(:company).where("companies.company_number is null").or(r.where(company_id: nil))
```

I don't understand why it makes a difference, but it apparently does.

Answer (score -1):

let's use

```
r.joins(:company).where(companies: { id: nil }).or(r.joins(:company).where(companies: { company_number: nil }))
```

> The two relations must be structurally compatible: they must be
> scoping the same model, and they must differ only by where

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or